# Passing 2D part of a 3D multidimensional array as a 2D method parameter array in C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, parameter-passing

What I would like to do in my code is something like that below:

```
public static class DataClass
{
    public static byte[,,] Array3d = { { {0,0},{0,0}},{{0,0},{0,0}}};

}

class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        someMethod(DataClass.Array3d[0]);
        someMethod(DataClass.Array3d[1]);
    }

    void someMethod(byte[,])
    {
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there is some way to do what I am trying to when calling `someMethod()`. If not, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a jagged array instead:

```
static byte[,][] array3d
```

Comment: The one that would work in this case is `static byte[][,] array3d`. I tried it here, but it has the big inconvenient that I cannot initialize it the easy way I was planning. I am forced to use `new` operator and the static constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You could just pass your 3D-array to the method. There is nothing preventing you from doing only operations on the relevant 2D subsection in the method.

You could also use a jagged array, but that comes at a heavy cost which I'm not sure is acceptable if you use a 3D-array in the first place.

Comment: Yes, but then it would cause coupling problems if the array and the method standed in distinct classes, as is in my project here. I will correct the example for a better representation.